# Warned about suspicious crypto mining on my harmless jenkins instance on GCP

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline, google-kubernetes-engine, cryptocurrency

I am a new user of google cloud platform and I have recently created a software app for which I wanted to implement CICD (continuous integration and continuous delivery) pipeline that deploys my latest code changes from github to google kubernetes engine by using Jenkins virtual machine.

2 days later, I received a warning email saying cryptocurrency activity was detected on my jenkins vm and so it was suspended.
I submitted appeal form explaining the purpose of my app and why I created jenkins vm.
Then I received an email today saying, "We found evidence of crypto mining activity which is against TOS. Please make necessary checks and fixes. After that, let us know of what checks and fixes were done, and we will evaluate the case."

I have no idea what "checks/fixes" to do here. I am new to the world of DevOps and GCP.
I am just a harmless software programmer.
My mistake was adding a firewall that allows 0.0.0.0/0 all inbound traffic.

Since the jenkins vm instance tagged with crypto mining was already suspended/stopped by gcp, I don't know what else is to be done.

What is the best response to this?
Can someone please let me know how to respond to them so that they close this matter right here without charging me/taking other action against me?
I've heard of hackers taking over jenkins instance to do mining, but how do I tell these people it was the hackers and not me. I assumed that some AI program detected it first and an actual human would be able to figure it out after reading my appeal. But it doesn't look like it.

I don't even need that jenkins instance since I am done learning/practicing CICD.

I already submitted an appeal form immediately after receiving the first email warning from them, explaining why I created the jenkins vm instance and that I do not need it anymore as I am finished with building my app and testing CICD.

Comment: You're going to have better success working with GCP support, since they'd presumably have records of the activity they suspect is mining.  All anybody here can do is guess what happened.

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks for the response. since they already suspended/stopped my jenkins vm instance and since I don't need that vm anymore, what do I respond to them? I just want them to end the matter here without charging/billing me for crypto activity. What do you think is the best response to their email?

Comment: Delete the VM. You are responsible for charges up to this point. Note: I have personally investigated these incident reports for customers. Google was correct every time. You did something or failed to do something to secure the VM.

Comment: If YOU allowed all inbound traffic, that was probably not a good idea. YOU are relying on the security of the Jenkins application as YOU configured it, the GCP/GKE configuration YOU set up and the authentication YOU had in place. Odds are someone got in, set up a crypto op and now YOU are on the hook. Even happens to enterprises with dedicated and certified experts. Be happy Google detected early and hopefully your bill is not too big.